# SciLab -> problem with graphics -> black window

Tags: scilab

I tried to use Xcos for any basic simulation, but I obtained a blank/black window, instead the graph.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AN78dFcH6eYs5ajpmGj4qtqH40smoghc

I was thinking that maybe I use wrong elements, but after running example from help I saw the same - black window.

At the end I tried to use simple "plot([1,2],[1,2]);" - the same.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sKexRkM8ZFB2DsqWEpShiFGgKhViXxCk

I tried to restart computer and to install older version (5.5.2 instead of 6.1.0) -> without changes.

System: Windows (I'm sorry) 7, 32 bit (yes, I used 32-bit instalation).

Answer (score 0):

I have so far no idea of what can procude such a behaviour;
Can you try the following sequence of instructions:

```
 f=gcf(); //what is the color of the xindow?
 f.background=5;// does the window background changes (red)?
 gca().background=5;// does the drawing area background changes(red)?
```

Comment: The window is still black, but the latter command generated an error 2 ("incorrect factor/element").
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vUINAPOrt2PgUg0xl2tBwNRooMRZpuEM
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b9l7w7JYqR-6SEKlz_5nQXo4CJEcgtZP
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oigWELOEfx3ANo85e4fAWRUillpx53CY